# What qualifies as "Magic"?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

With the introduction of forging Sacred Seals, 3 new seals were added that are designed to reduce incoming damage from consecutive attacks.
One reduces damage from melee ranged, physical attacks. ([Deflect Melee X](https://fireemblem.gamepress.gg/sacred-seal/deflect-melee-3) applies to swords, lances, axes)
One reduces damage from long ranged, physical attacks. ([Deflect Missle X](https://fireemblem.gamepress.gg/sacred-seal/deflect-missile-3) applies to bows and daggers)
The third one, [Deflect Magic X](https://fireemblem.gamepress.gg/sacred-seal/deflect-magic-3), just states "Magic".

I was wondering what qualifies as "magic" in the sense of this seal's damage reduction?
Namely, will this seal reduce damage from consecutive attacks made by tome users and dragonstone users (as both use the Res stat for damage calculation), or simply one or the other?

Comment: According to [this](https://feheroes.gamepedia.com/Mechanics#Physical.2FMagical_Damage_Weapons) guide, magic based attacks are Tomes, Breaths, and Neutral Staff. However it's been a while since I've played FE heroes, so I'm not sure if the new seals would affect  all 3

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about Heroes, but in the FE series magic is any damage that is reduced by RES (Resistance). In Heroes that would be Tomes, Dragon Breaths, and Staves. In other FE games, weapons like Armads or Raijinto are physical in melee, and magical at range. I don't know how Heroes handles those weapons, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works on all tomes, **but** not staffs or breath attacks. Also, the user must be hit twice in a row, without countering in between.

[Healers not affected](https://www.reddit.com/r/FireEmblemHeroes/comments/78oyvt/healers_are_not_affected_by_deflect_magic/)

[Tome users only](https://fireemblem.gamepress.gg/q-a/deflect-magic-only-works-tome-users)

[Doesn't affect dragons](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/204447-fire-emblem-heroes/75860307?page=1)

[Yup](https://www.reddit.com/r/FireEmblemHeroes/comments/75dada/deflect_magic_and_dragonstones/do5a3nt/)

Answer (score 0):

A magic attack is any attack that is affected by [the defender's Res stat](https://rankedboost.com/fire-emblem-heroes/stats/).  This includes breath attacks, tome attacks, and staff attacks.

The Deflect Magic sacred seal is therefore best utilized by heroes that have a low enough speed that they may be attacked twice, and a low enough resistance that they likely won't survive two full magic attacks.